# Сортировка полей после чтения их из БД

Tags: c#, сортировка

есть модель

```
public class Model
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public double Price {get;set;}
    public DateTime FinishSelDate {get;set;}
}
```

функция которая вычитает данные с БД по модели (подробности опускаю)

```
public List<ModelDTO> GetData()
{
    return context.ModelRepository.Read()// Прочитает все модели из БД
    .OrederBy(m => m.Title) // Отсортирует оп убываню по названию
    .Select(t => new ModelDTO
        { //TODO 
        })
    .ToList();
}
```

Можно как-то написать универсальную функцию для сортировки любого поля???

хотелось бы вроде такого что-то:

```
public List<ModelDTO> GetData(Dictionary<string,string> sort){//TODO}
```

где `sort` - `{"Title","Asc"}` - поле и как сортировать

Т. е. вопрос в том, как потом эту `стрингу`- `Title` впихнуть в `OrderBy`???

Comment: Посмотрите DynamicLinq, там в параметр OrderBy можно строку передавать

Comment: Эти строки всегда в коде или передаются/настраиваются пользователем? Обязательно ли это должны быть строки. Например, вариант `GetData(m => m.Title)` не подойдет?

Comment: @defaultlocale передоваться должна название поля, которое нудно отсортировать, и как именно нужно это делать (словарь для удобства т к в реале параметр не один)

Comment: В `Price`, судя по названию, явно хранятся деньги. Ни в коем случае нельзя использовать тип `double`. Только `decimal`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov знаю ) это я набросал для имитации своей проблемы на легком примере...на быструю руку...так что так вышло просто

Answer (score 1):

Подключите в NuGet System.Linq.Dynamic.

Добавляете его в using и в коде сможете использовать конструкцию типа

```
public List<ModelDTO> GetData(string property, string orderType)
{
    return context.ModelRepository.Read()
    .OrederBy(property + " " + orderType)
    .Select(t => new ModelDTO
        { //TODO 
        })
    .ToList();
}
```

orderType значения "ASC" или "DESC"

Если надо несколько сортируемых параметров, то их следует сформировать в строку через запятую (например "поле1 DESC, поле2 ASC")

Comment: не хочется что-то лишнее юзать.. +1 вам )

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string GetReflectedPropertyValue(this object subject, string field)
{
    object reflectedValue = subject.GetType().GetProperty(field).GetValue(subject, null);
    return reflectedValue != null ? reflectedValue.ToString() : "";
}
```

использование

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
persons.Add(new Person("Вася", 12, "4Б"));
persons.Add(new Person("Петя", 12, "11А"));
persons.Add(new Person("Галя", 19, "11А"));
persons.Add(new Person("Анна", 15, "6А"));

var result2 = persons.OrderByDescending(p => p.GetReflectedPropertyValue("Age")).ToList();
```

Comment: Вы сортируете по строковому представлению свойства. Как у вас отсортируются, например, числа от 0 до 30?

Comment: @tym32167 вы говорите о том, что числа будут представлены в виде стринга? Дак это можно добавить логики просто

Comment: Я в принципе не очень понимаю смысла в такой задаче и немного сомневаюсь в эффективности, но на полную реализацию я бы глянул :)

Comment: @tym32167 смысл - есть таблица, которая тащится с БД на 25 колонок...нужно сортировать по каждой (на выбор пользователя). Одновременно может быть отсортирована одна колонка.

Comment: Вы всю таблицу в память читаете? Почему нельзя сортировку доверить базе данных?

Comment: @tym32167 что значит "доверить БД"? сортировать данные не после того как я вытащил данные, а на этапе формирования `IQurable`? Через `Expression` ?

Comment: Ну да, сортировать так, чтобы база данных получила поле для сортировки. А то сейчас получается как только вы начнете слать запросы с ограничением по количеству элементов, типа `топ 10`, то вам надо будет либо вытаскивать все данные в память, сортировать и возвращать топ 10, или вы будете возвращать неверные данные

Comment: @tym32167 дак не получилось...щас кину как пробовал

Comment: Я у черта на рогах с телефона, потому что то проверить/ запустить смогу только завтра или через пару дней, если не забуду ))

Comment: Но гугл показывает это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265186/how-do-i-specify-the-linq-orderby-argument-dynamically , там второй ответ вроде

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void SortBy(string field, ListSortDirection type)
    {
        var propertyInfo = typeof(Student).GetProperty(field);
        students = type == ListSortDirection.Ascending ? students.OrderBy(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null)).ToList() : students.OrderByDescending(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null)).ToList();
    }
```

Использование

```
persons.SortBy("Age", ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо за наводку

Comment: Не, не то. Это материализует коллекцию, а этого желательно избежать

Answer (score 0):

Еще один метод сортировки через `Expression tree`

```
private static IEnumerable<T> GetSortedData<T>(IQueryable<T> list, string sortColumnName) 
{ 
    var type = typeof(T); 
    var property = type.GetProperty(sortColumnName); 
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p"); 
    var propertyAccess = Expression.Property(parameter, property); 
    var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter); 
    MethodCallExpression resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderBy", new[] { type, property.PropertyType }, list.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExp)); 
    return (IEnumerable<T>)Expression.Lambda(resultExp).Compile().DynamicInvoke(); 
}
```